# Get Weeks start date when week start is different year and week end is different year

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Today is 30-12-2013 and in my sql server week is start from Sunday.Its mean week start 29-12-2013
and week end date is saturday 4-1-2014.

I want week start date using end date 4-1-2014.Is there any way to find week start date when date is two on different years.

I got the week start date and end date of week when years are same.But I want week start date when both years are different.

Answer (score 1):

JUST SUBTRACT DAYS TO END DATE,  EXAMPLE:

```
 SELECT GETDATE() - 7
```

ADDING (+/-) DAYS IS THE SAME IF YOU REPLACE GETDATE() WITH A DATETIME COLUMN OR @VARIABLE

Comment: I want week start date using end date

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @date DATE; 
SET @date = '20140104';

SELECT DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @date)-1), @date) [Week Start],
       DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @date)), @date) [WeekEnd]
```

**Result**

```
╔════════════╦════════════╗
║ Week Start ║  WeekEnd   ║
╠════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2013-12-29 ║ 2014-01-04 ║
╚════════════╩════════════╝
```